# toolbar title reset by Activity when using androidx.navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

using androidx.navigation the toolbar-title ist set automatically when using `android.label` in the `nav_graph`. this works fine until a configuration-change (e.g. rotate the device) happens. after this, the toolbar-title is reset to the app-title.

it seems that the activity is re-setting the title in `Activity.onPostCreate()` after navigation's `ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener` has set it after the rotation.

Comment: I've created an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177171539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up toolbar both with navigation graph and as a support action bar.

```
val appCompat = requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity
appCompat.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
appCompat.setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI) for more information.

Comment: That's what I did and I think that's also the problem. Because I set my toolbar as the SupportActionBar, Activity.onPostCreate() overwrites the title (it sets the title of the SupportActionBar which is my Toolbar).

Comment: My fault, I was using setupWithNavController() instead of  setupActionBarWithNavController(). Now it works. Thanks.